How to make exim run the queue upon connection on a Chromebook?
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/exim4 runs the queue upon connection.
Except on a Chromebook, where one uses wifi, not ppp.
So if one boots at 3PM, sends a mail offline at 3:05, connects to the network at 3:15,... well the mail will still sit around until 3:30 when exim's half-hourly run finally takes place.

Just do runq -qqf, that will flush the queue for you.

Thanks, but you don't get my point. I want the queue flushed automatically upon wifi connection.
